# MS Access SQL - Count if a field matches either of two criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, criteria

I have a table that contains employees attendance details.  For this example let’s assume only three different attendance types: ‘Holiday’ /  ‘Bank-Holiday’ / ‘Sickness’.

I can find the totals of each for each employee without difficulty, however I need to combine the results from ‘Holiday’ and ‘Bank-Holiday’.

---

e.g.  if the table contained the following data:

John  - ‘Holiday’

John  - ‘Bank-Holiday’

John  - ‘Sickness’

Jenny – ‘Holiday’

---

The results should be

Name - Days Sick – Days Holiday

John – 1 – 2

Jenny – 0 - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents' worth:

Instead of hard-coding this type of categorization into queries you *really* should create an [AbsenceCategories] table with values like...

```
AbsenceType     AbsenceCategory
-----------     ---------------
Sickness        Sick
Holiday         Holiday
Bank-Holiday    Holiday
```

...so when "Top Management" sends you the memo informing you that "Unscheduled Absence" must be tracked separately and categorized as "Holiday" then you can just add it to your table and you don't have to change all of your queries and such.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, will try them out when back at work tomorrow.

My initial approach was the same as Gareth's answer, seemed like Access wasn't accepting IIF in SQL statements, but I could well have made some other small syntax error.  However I'm probally going to opt for Gord's approach.  The example given is highly simplified from the actual situation (indeed absence and sickness are already treated seperately).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IIF` inside a SUM Statement to count certain conditions:

```
SELECT  [YourTable].[Name],
        SUM(IIF([YourTable].[Attendance] = 'Sickness', 1, 0)) AS [Days Sick],
        SUM(IIF([YourTable].[Attendance] IN ('Holiday' , 'Bank-Holiday'), 1, 0)) AS [Days Holiday]
FROM    [YourTable]
GROUP BY [YourTable].[Name];
```

Comment: Change made (did both), I should really practice what I preach, only this morning I said that column references should always be aliased to avoid problems with future schema changes.

Comment: Whichever approach I finally decide on, will try again with IIF in Access SQL anyway.  The project is fairly massive, and will be useful to get this to work this way also.

Answer (score 0):

You want a conditional aggregation, something like:

```
select name,
       sum(iif(which = 'Sickness', 1, 0)) as SickDays,
       sum(iif(which = 'Holiday' or which = 'Bank Holiday', 1, 0)) as Holiday
from t
group by name
```